# How to update running WKInterfaceImage animation?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I´m working on a custom rectangular timer as a WKInterfaceImage in my iWatch. The idea is to set the duration as the length on the timer and then animate the timer shrinking to length = 0. It works fine as long as it´s allowed to run the whole animation. But If I try to change the timer length wile the animation is running it adds the new length to the current length.

So basically the problem is that when I try to add a new length it´s combines the old and new length to the timer which makes it far to long.

Would really appreciate some help.

Here´s the code:

```
    -(void)setAnimatedTimer {
        NSLog(@"timer called");

        NSUserDefaults* defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.daypal"];
        NSDate *NextActivityStartTime = [defaults objectForKey:@"watchStartDate"];
        NSDate *NextActivityEndTime = [defaults objectForKey:@"watchStopDate"];

        NSTimeInterval fromStartTimeToNow = [NextActivityStartTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
        NSTimeInterval fromEndTimeToNow = [NextActivityEndTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
        NSTimeInterval watchDuration = fromEndTimeToNow - fromStartTimeToNow;
        if (fromStartTimeToNow > 0 && fromEndTimeToNow > 0) {
            _watchActivityTimer.hidden = YES;

int watbchdurationlenght = watchDuration/100;

     [self.watchActivityTimer setRelativeWidth:watchDurationLenght withAdjustment:0.0];

 [self animateWithDuration:watchDuration animations:^{
        //  [self.watchActivityTimer setHorizontalAlignment:WKInterfaceObjectHorizontalAlignmentRight];
        [self.watchActivityTimer setWidth:0];

    }];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It worked when I added blocks. When the animation is running it creates the bugg with the length. But when I stop the animation before starting a new animation it solved the problem.

```
[self animateWithDuration:fromEndTimeToNow animations:^{

       [self.watchActivityTimer stopAnimating]; }
       completion:^{
           [self animateWithDuration:fromEndTimeToNow animations:^{
        [self.watchActivityTimer setRelativeWidth:0.0 withAdjustment:0.0];
           }
           completion:^{
               NSLog(@"timer animation completed");
               [self MessageiPhoneForNewActivity];

    }];

       }];}
```